# Можно ли использовать autoload вне фреймворка?

Tags: php, composer

Вот есть установленный композером Бутстрап.

Могу ли я как-то указать файлу пхп что нужно грузить автолоад из папки вендор?

Или ручками путь указывать в любом случае?

Comment: не совсем понятно, вам хочется без require '/vendor/autoload.php' обойтись в своем скрипте? имх так не получится и инклудить всеравно придется...

Comment: Я хочу обойтись без  <link href="vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: композер с аволоадом классов только по теме php кода работает, бутстрап и его css - это совсем другая область ведь

Comment: т.е. через автолоад нельзя подключить js и css?

Comment: нет, автолоад композера работает только с классами и неймспейсами php, а бутстрап в композере по другим причинам, вас видимо это и запутало, по сути его там быть и  не должно вообще

Comment: composer для backend'a то есть php-пакеты, для frontaend'a используйте, например bower это менеджер пакетов как и composer только для css/js и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы всегда обязаны подключать файл композера вручную, прописывая путь к `vendor/autoload.php`

Подключение из Вашего index.php

```
$composerAutoload = __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; 
require_once "$composerAutoload";
```

Делать это можно из любого php-файла в том числе и вне любых фреймворков и cms

Comment: можно код? include('vendor/autoload.php'); чет не подключает бутстрап

Comment: $composerAutoload = 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
require_once "$composerAutoload";

Comment: пропишите относительный или абсолютный путь к композеру. Если пришлёте структуру папок и файлов я напишу путь для подключения

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/QAxEAD8.jpg

Comment: исправил ответ проверьте